# ¿Cuál es el origen de "churri" como apelativo cariñoso en relaciones amorosas?

Tags: coloquialismos, españa

En España se usa mucho, en el ámbito coloquial, el apelativo *churri* para mencionar a la persona querida, especialmente en parejas:

> —Buenos días, **churri**, ¿cómo has dormido?

Se ha extendido bastante y tiene un toque cursi que hace que se use especialmente en la intimidad, pero también tiene la otra variante de que ya se usa para parodiar estas situaciones. También, a veces se usa para designar a las mujeres en un contexto de ligoteo:

> En esa playa hay muchas churris.

Al ser una palabra relativamente nueva, regional y coloquial, no me sorprende que el DLE no la recoja, si bien recoge una acepción del término desde 1992:

> [**churri**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=966tqW7)
>   1. adj. Andalucía. Gárrulo, enfadoso y sin sustancia.

Vemos cómo aumenta su uso [según Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=churri&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchurri%3B%2Cc0):

> [image]

Además, se usa especialmente en Cataluña, [según Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=ES&q=churri), si bien en catalán no hay una palabra equivalente:

> [image]

Entonces: ¿cuál es el origen de la palabra? ¿En qué zonas se usa y entiende?

Comment: Curioso, no hay que confundir un [gárrulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Iy7EpfQ) con un [garrulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Iy5kUyz).

Comment: @Charlie ¡cierto! Si bien el DLE indica que probablemente _garrulo_ venga de _gárrulo_, supongo que de _Dicho de una persona: Muy habladora o charlatana._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es una abreviación de [*pichurri*](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/37541-pichurri) que tiene la misma significación de un mote cariñoso.<sup>1</sup> No tengo prueba, pero me parece posible que sea una corrupción de los apelativos *[pichón](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/40875-pich-n), [pichoncita](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/40876), pichoncito*, etc.

ej.

> —¡Pichurri, cariño! ¿Sigues ahí?
>
> —¡Sí, Pichón! Estoy bien. Enseguida voy p'allá.
>
> - [*Amar en tiempos revueltos*](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/amar-en-tiempos-revueltos/amar-tiempos-revueltos-t3-capitulo-147/11293/) - T3 - Capítulo 147

Según [*Sociolingüistica urbana: el habla de Bilbao*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=2Eea_6UmFUsC&q=pichurri) (Maitena Etxebarria Arostegui, p.109 No.220), además se usa en Bilbao y [también](https://alcumes.jimdo.com/2-alcumes-modernos-despois-1950/pp/) en Galícia.

---

*La gran enciclopedia vasca, Volumen 1*, propone (con dudas) que viene del vasco *pitxin*:

> Como voces sinónimas de pichín, se usan también con las mozas las siguientes: *pichirri, pichurri, pichurrín, pichurrina*
>
> ¿Del vasc. *pitxin* 'poquitín, pequeñín', variante de *pitin* 'id.'? De todos modos, parece evidente su relación con el lat. vg. *pittinu*(m) 'pequeño'. Véase: J. Corominas, *DCEC*, v. III, pag. 47 x ss.
>
> - [*La gran enciclopedia vasca, Volumen 11*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=vd8pAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=pichurri) (p.146) (1966)

---

1. **pichurri** (inf.) n. Se emplea como *apelativo cariñoso.
   [*María Moliner*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/churri.1996156/)

Comment: @joseph_jaroslav fixed the typo and added another source for the meaning of *pichurri*.