# Best nickname for "shortie"?

Tags: coloquialismos, diminutivos, citas

What is a good nickname for "shortie" that a guy can call a girl in Spanish, which is cute and teasing (diminutive), but not hurtful (pejorative)?

- bajita?
- chaparrita? (Is this only understood in Mexico?)
- pequeña? (Is this too generic to apply to a person?)
- enana? (Is this pejorative?)
- petisa?
- retacona?
- Something else?

(This is really a question about nuances and how universally nicknames might be understood across Latin America...)

Comment: What dialects of Spanish are you asking about? For instance, in Argentina (and possibly others), it is common to use *flaca/flaco* or _gorda/gordo_ as diminutives but they would be surprising in Spain.

Comment: It doesn't matter which dialect. Certain things are the same across Spanish-speaking countries: Bajito/Bajita for example. Just like: Gordito/Gordita. I don't know the specific ones except Peque, for Spain.

Comment: Right, I'm looking for a term that can be universally understood across dialects. It has to be cute and diminutive, but it has to work for adult women.

Answer (score 5):

Algunos de esos diminutivos podrían ser:

- **Chiqui**: asociado a la palabra "chiquitita", hace referencia a algo pequeño y se utiliza en modo cariñoso. Se utiliza tanto para hombres como para mujeres y su procedencia puede estar en la palabra "txiki" del euskera que significa pequeño.
- **Peque**: asociado a la palabra "pequeña" se suele utilizar tanto para hombres como para mujere.
- **Bebé**: este es más utilizado en latino-América y tiene una connotación cariñosa.
- **Churri**: algo más alejado del significado de "pequeño" aunque su [origen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26987/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-churri-como-apelativo-cari%C3%B1oso-en-relaciones-amorosas) puede estar en la palabra "pichón" y podría vincularse de alguna manera.

Comment: _Peque_ tends to be used more for children than for adults, perhaps.

Comment: OK, so I think chiqui is the best name for a flirting context? Does it have a "little girl" connotation, or can it be used for short but full-grown women?

Comment: @LukeHutchison Peque and Chiqui can be used in your context in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, as @LukeHutchison says, "Peque" and "Chiqui" can be used even the person is not "short".  In Spain it is also said "Gordi" in a lovingly way even the person is not fat.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answer, I'd like to mention that "bajita" and "retacona" could be used to describe, but not to call a girl. "Retacona" suggests not only "short", but also "plump" or "sturdy".

"Enana" and "petisa" can be used affectionately if the relationship is close. Otherwise, they will sound pejorative.

As vocatives, all of these work well:

- Petisa, ¿cómo estás?
- Peti, ¿cómo estás?
- Enana, ¿cómo estás?
- Chiqui, ¿cómo estás?
- Peque, ¿cómo estás?

All of these can also be used with an article to refer to that person:

- Hoy vino la petisa / la peti / la enana / la chiqui / la peque. (They may also be written with a capital.)

In Argentina, there are at least three famous women who are called this way:

- [La Peque Pareto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paula_Pareto) (judo champion)
- [La Chiqui Legrand](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirtha_Legrand) (actress, entertainer)
- [La Enana Feudale](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcela_Feudale) (journalist)

Comment: Those people may be called that, that doesn't mean they are general names for a small person. My husband who is from Sevilla and a Spanish writer said he never heard petisa or peti. Maybe those are Catalan, near the Spanish border with France?

Comment: @Lambie - "Petisa" is not Catalan, although "petita" means small in Catalan - but it's not something I would call an adult in their face.

Comment: @Pere I'm not saying it is. But petita can have come from French.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, according to the DRAE, petisa comes from the French word petit. Does your husband read comics? Superlópez is a classic. ;-P

Comment: @RubioRic Aha, see I was right about that. I don't know about what comics he reads. Will ask him.